# Correct sentence structure, Withdraw deposit

Tags: grammar

Our UI designer is saying that our link option 'Withdraw deposit funds" is a correct and acceptable structure.

I argue that we should make it "Withdraw/deposit funds" or "Withdraw or deposit funds", but he is does not agree.

What is the grammatically correct structure?

Comment: As others have said,  'Withdraw deposit funds' is incorrect. In fact, as a native speaker of English, I could not understand what it meant. I assumed that 'deposit' must be adjectival. This would mean that there were things called 'deposit-funds' and that the link allows you to withdraw them. I assumed that 'deposit funds' were some kind of savings account.  Very misleading.  Word order and punctuation are crucial in English because there is very little grammatical inflection.

Answer (score 4):

You're absolutely right, "Withdraw deposit funds" sounds idiotic.

"Withdraw/Deposit Funds" is okay.

"Withdraw or Deposit Funds" is better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "or" or "and" between "withdraw" and "depoisit".

In any English sentence, it is ungrammatical to use two verbs in one sentence without any conjunction. [***Independent clause***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_clause) well explains this point:

> An independent clause (or main clause) is a clause that can stand by
>   itself as a simple sentence. An independent clause ***contains a subject
>   and a [predicate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/predicate)***; it makes sense by itself and therefore expresses a
>   complete thought.

[Wikipedia]

That's why using "withdraw deposit funds" is ungrammatical if "deposit" is meant to be used as a "verb". You need a conjunction between them. Otherwise, "deposit funds" could be misinterpreted as a ***[compound noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/compound-noun?q=compound+noun)*** meaning "funds deposited".

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: "Rage, rage against the dying of the light."  That's two.

Comment: @deadrat "Run, run, Forrest, run!" That's three.

Comment: But I read on ELU that it's ungrammatical to use two verbs in one sentence.

Comment: @deadrat Do you believe everything you read? I know where you are taking this and it is off-topic. If you have a better answer, put one for yourself.

Comment: You mean I shouldn't?  Even if you wrote it?